# I get an Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, typescript, react-table

I am trying to display my data on a table using react table but i keep getting the error

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

well totally new error, at least im getting somewhere, thank you :)

I am using TypeOrm, typegraphql, graphql code generator

***this is the query i am using in my resolver folder:***

```
@Query(() => [RawTicketResponse], { nullable: true })
    async findRawAssignedTickets(
        @Ctx() { req }: MyContext
    ): Promise<RawTicketResponse[]> {
        const isUser = await User.findOne(req.session.UserId);
        const assignedTickets = await getRepository(Ticket)
            .createQueryBuilder('ticket')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('ticket.assignedDeveloper', 'assignedDeveloper')
            .where('ticket.assignedDeveloperId = :id', { id: isUser?.id })
            .getRawMany();

        console.log('data: ', JSON.stringify(assignedTickets, null, 2));
        return assignedTickets;
    }
```

***here are the columns i am importing:***

```
export const TICKET_COLUMNS = [
    {
        Header: 'Title',
        accessor: 'ticket_title',
    },
    {
        Header: 'Description',
        accessor: 'ticket_text',
    },
    {
        Header: 'Priority',
        accessor: 'ticket_priority',
    },
    {
        Header: 'Status',
        accessor: 'ticket_status',
    },
    {
        Header: 'Type',
        accessor: 'ticket_type',
    },
    {
        Header: 'Developer',
        accessor: 'assignedDeveloper_Id',
    },
];
```

***this is the table component i am trying to make:***

```
    import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
    import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { useTable } from 'react-table';
    import {
        useFindAssignedTicketsQuery,
        useFindRawAssignedTicketsQuery,
    } from '../generated/graphql';
    import { TICKET_COLUMNS } from './Columns';
    import MOCK_DATA from './MOCK_DATA.json';
    import REAL_DATA from './REAL_DATA.json';
    
    export const NewTable = () => {
        const [{ data: ticketData }] = useFindRawAssignedTicketsQuery();
        if (!ticketData?.findRawAssignedTickets) {
            return <>no data</>;
        }
    
        let realData = ticketData?.findRawAssignedTickets;
    
    
    
        const columns = useMemo<
            Column<{
                title: string;
                text: string;
                priority: string;
                status: string;
                type: string;
                developer: string;
            }>[]
        >(() => TICKET_COLUMNS, []);
        const data = useMemo(() => realData, []);
    
        const {
            getTableProps,
            getTableBodyProps,
            headerGroups,
            rows,
            prepareRow,
        } = useTable({
            columns,
            data,
        });
    
        return (
            <Table
                {...getTableProps()}
                striped
                bordered
                hover
                responsive
                variant="dark"
            >
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {rows.map((row) => {
                        prepareRow(row);
                        return (
                            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                    return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>;
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    };
```

Comment: `realData = JSON.stringify` and you expect it not to be string?..

Comment: yes, see, I am relatively new at this so I am unaware as to how it works, I am trying to take my data into an array of JSON objects, i thought that stringify just added quotes to all the keys and string values i know it seems obvious due to the name, that it would be a string, but keep in mind stringify wasnt my first attempt, it was just the thing that got the console log to look right, but came at the added cost of turning the type into a string, and as a beginner not seeing quotation marks in the log, you can see my confusion

Comment: No worries. You don't need quotation marks over object keys, they should be all right as they are. Can you get rid `JSON.stringify` and update your post with the error you're getting and a screenshot of `console.log(realData)`? it'll make it a bit easier to investigate.

Comment: thank you! once i ditched the JSON stringify  i realized that part of my problem was my component didn't have access to context so i was missing an arg for the query and thus it was returning nothing. now im getting a new error, i tried to screenshot, but im on i3wm so i don't know how to take screenshots

Comment: Can't help you with the screenshot, but you can always take a picture with a phone :) Copying the error also helps

Answer (score 0):

I eventually realized that i cant put  hook in a conditional, so instead i used a ternary statement which worked an now i have my component working!